# MATLAB: How can we change the cost function of Autoencoder

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, autoencoder

I want to change the cost function of Autoencoder in MATLAB instead of the traditional cost function that minimizes the reconstruction error. Can I do it directly by explicitly mentioning it somewhere? OR do I have to go in the code of Autoencoder. Can you please suggest me the location where I may have to make changes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you would have to change the code itself, since there doesn't appear to be any way of changing the [cost function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/trainautoencoder.html#buythiv-1). Specifically, the [`'LossFunction'` parameter](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/trainautoencoder.html#input_argument_d0e46605) passed to [`trainAutoencoder`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/trainautoencoder.html) appears to have `'msesparse'` as the only option available.

However, you can change 2 coefficients of the cost function: the [`'L2WeightRegularization'` coefficient](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/trainautoencoder.html#input_argument_d0e46562) and the [`'SparsityRegularization'` coefficient](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/trainautoencoder.html#input_argument_d0e46744). The form of the [L<sub>2</sub> Regularization](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/trainautoencoder.html#buyr01q-1) and [Sparsity Regularization](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/trainautoencoder.html#buyr01b-1) terms appear fixed, though. It's just their relative weighting that is changed in the cost function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Specifically, I want to modify cost function as (xi-ci)^2, where ci is the mean of the class of the objects. Right now, the Loss Function use (xi-x'i) type of notation to reconstruct. I want to reconstruct based on the mean of the class. Do you have ideas on how to do that?